# How to control the power to an LED strip using a micro switch?

Tags: power-supply, switches, led-strip

I've never worked with electronics before so I want to be sure I do things correctly and safely.

I have this [LED strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015R87GQK) which is powered by a 5V USB port. I would like to control the power to the strip using a micro limit switch similar to [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NSRHK3).

Is it safe to just splice the switch in-between the power adaptor and LED strip? If not, what is the proper way to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: well, your limit switch has a datasheet. That will list the permissible switched current.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this can, and can only be, answered from the datasheet of the device in question.

Comment: It is a momentary switch. LEDs on only when you press it. Find a latching switch. You may find a rocker switch, rated above 1 amps.

Comment: @ocrdu: I reverted your edit. The datasheet you added seemed to be for a different switch.

Comment: @Marcus-Müller: Yes, could be, same type number but different manufacturer (https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/V-153-1C25/1829013), sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess you missed the "I'm totally new to electronics" thing? The datasheet means absolutely nothing to me. As a doctor, let me know the next time you need to close a wound so I can send you descriptions of polydioxanone, poliglecaprone, polyglactin suture material.

Comment: @Offswitch sorry, this is a platform about electrical engineering. The ability to read a current from a table is to be expected, even of medical experts.

Comment: @marcus this site does not have a minimum skill required. Beginners and hobbyists are welcomed too.

Comment: @Passerby no doubt that we don't expect a finished EE degree, but "it's the current in the table of the datasheet" is low-level enough that I don't see why we can't expect people to read the table once they get that info. If the table remains unclear, they're welcome to ask back. They don't need to sass me with a biochemical analogy.

Comment: @marcus you sassed first with a rtfm type comment.

Comment: huh? @Passerby If I did, that wasn't intentional – what's sassy about saying "well, your limit switch has a datasheet. That will list the permissible switched current."? That's exactly the answer to the question.

Comment: Your ignoring your other comment which has a much ruder tone.

Comment: @Passerby I'm assuming you mean the close vote comment, then? I'm not sure what's rude about saying that the question can't be answered without a datasheet, and that it can be answered by the datasheet, which OP will have to find for the device they want to buy.

Comment: Two people see it as rude. Don't know what to tell you beyond that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'd like to thank the commenters who acknowledged my lack of expertise in this area. Honestly, I didn't even know that a component like a micro switch had an associated "datasheet". If there is a better place for me to ask simple electronics questions in the future please let me know.

Comment: @Offswitch you're more than welcome to ask them here. I simply didn't mean to be rude, and as it seems, you and I both agree that it was a good thing for you to learn about datasheets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two important specs you need to look for here are the current/voltage of your device, and the current/voltage of your switch.

In this case the usb led strip is 5V DC and 10 Watts or up to 2 Amps, as is, without cutting it down. The actual draw may be lower, but let's go with that as the expected maximum.

A typical micro lever switch will have a higher AC rating than a DC rating. It's a factor of how the switches work and how the voltage source functions. Your specific switch is rated at 0.6A at 120V DC. You could make an assumption that it would be okay at lower voltages and higher current, but the failure mode of the switch would not make that a safe assumption. Best case it fails prematurely, open/corrods or closed/fuses. Worst case, fire. So we can assume that it can take 0.6A at 5V. Thats a quarter of what we need.

So you need a better switch, a lower current device, or use the switch to trigger another option, like a relay. Plenty of cheap DC capable relays. Any common 5V relay or relay module can switch 5 or 10 Amps with a coil that only needs a few hundred milliamps.

As for the wiring, yes you would splice the switch or the relay's switched connection in-between the power source and the led strip. In this case a usb extension cable would be an ideal source for a pig tail. You can splice into the 5V line or the ground. I would do the 5v. A fuse would be nice but likely unneeded.

Comment: I like this answer, but note that switches that have problems with 0.6 A of DC current might have a problem extinguishing the arc that happens when the kickback from a relay's coil comes.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you SO much for your explanation (and for your comments on the question itself).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yet another comment that provides no description of a proper alternative. It's almost like you enjoy *not* helping people.

Comment: @Offswitch I'm sorry that my comments don't help you! It's not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is rated for 15 A, which is typical (smaller ones are rated for 5 A or 10 A), and a USB port is rated for 1 A (or 2.1 A if you're Apple), so I see no problem with the component ratings.  If you want to hedge your bets, get a short USB extension cord, male on one end and female on the other, and splice the switch into that.  That way, if you make a mistake or want to undo things, you have not cut up the original wiring.

Comment: Hi, I don't see where that switch on amazon is rated for 15A; the description has wildly self-contradicting specs.

Comment: Table titled "Specifications for this item", third line.

Comment: yes, that lists the contradicting data: OP (probably) wants to switch DC, not AC; look into the "About this item" text:  *Rating: 15A, 1/2Hp, 125/250Vac; 0.6A,125Vdc; 0.3A, 250Vdc; 0.6A,125Vdc; 0.3A, 250Vdc*; for DC; the 15 A is plain wrong!

Answer (score 0):

So based on the specs of that switch, It's not rated for the power consumption (10 Watts, 5 VDC) of the LEDs.  Although it says 15A, thats for AC.  Its rated 0.3/0.6 A for 125/250 VDC.  You'll have to find something that is rated higher (say 5/2.5 A 125/250 VDC).

And as someone mentioned in the comments, this is a momentary switch, meaning that the lever will need to be held down in order for the LEDs to stay on.  Look for a latching switch.

You also don't need a SPDT switch.  You're only going to need 2 inputs and 2 outputs since its a charging USB cable (no data lines) with 2 leads.  The SPDT only has 3 terminals (1 input and 2 output). So you'll need a DPDT switch (2 inputs + 2 outputs).

Comment: A SPDT or SPST is fine here. Only need to switch one side.

Comment: I see. My mistake!